# TypeLITE with multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, typelite

I am using TypeLITE with various projects and a simple web site. I would like to use TypeLITE to generate TypeScript definitions from my C# classes, but I am not allowed to add the TypeLITE dll's to every project.

Let this be my project structure:

Solution
|
|
----- WebSite (with NuGet-Installation of TypeLITE)
|
|
----- FirstProject
|
|
----- SecondProject
|
|
----- ThirdProject

I installed TypeLITE via NuGet-Console and the C#-Classes are located in "FirstProject", "SecondProject" and "ThirdProject".

Problem: I have to use the NuGet-Installation for all other projects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use definitions of classes from the `FirstProject` in your `WebSite`, you can just add reference to the `FirstProject` to the `TypeLite.tt` file inside your `WebSite`

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)FirstProject.dll" #>
```

and classes from the `FirstProject` will become available to the TypeLITE.

(if FirstProject.dll isn't located in the bin folder of your `WebSite`, you have to use appropriate directory instead of `$(TargetDir)`)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. As I understand this, I have to add the "[TsClass]" entry to every class where I would like to use with the TypeLITE Scripts. But the [TsClass]-entry is not valid without the reference of TypeLite.dll

Comment: The `TsClass` attribute is only required for auto-discovery of classes by the `ForLoadedAsemblies` method. Instead of using the `ForLoadedAsemblies` method, you can add classes manually to the model - `TypeScript.Definitions().For<YourClass1>().For<YourClass2>()`

Comment: @LukasKabrt do you have any idea how to customise guid properties to be of type any in ts using typelite? It just creates an interface guid definition. WebEssentials create a property of type any but that's manual approach by right click context menu!